# Apply theme to Classic ASP website?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

One client asked about their website which was developed in Classic ASP with JavaScript and VBScript. I have very limited knowledge about Classic ASP because I have been doing ASP.Net all my life.

My question is, is it possible to change the theme for the website without having to touch any of the programming part? I mean only the interface/look of the website by using any ready template theme like themeforest or else.

I hope anyone here can advice me about this.

Comment: Without knowing how it was originally written there is no way to answer this question.

Comment: There is no concept of themes in classic ASP. But it is impossible to answer your question in the scope of StackOverflow with the information given. Is the business logic tightly coupled to the display logic? Has CSS been used effectively so that you can  use that as the mechanism of your theme change?

Answer (score 1):

This is generally done using Include files that write HTML for headers, footers, navigation, etc. Create a sample HTML file that draws the look you want for your ASP Web App and leave a placeholder in the content area where already-existing content should go. Then split up the area before the existing content (theHead.inc) and after (theFooter.inc), and use Include in all files to place the HTML before and after the content, respectively.